# Modify existing WCF communication object

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework

This is how I used to make method calls:

```
SvcHelper.Using<SomeWebServiceClient>(proxy =>
{
   proxy.SomeMethod();
}

public class SvcHelper
{
   public static void Using<TClient>(Action<TClient> action) where TClient : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable, new()
   {
   }
}
```

This is how I make method calls:

```
ChannelFactory<ISomethingWebService> cnFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomethingWebService>("SomethingWebService");
ISomethingWebService client = cnFactory.CreateChannel();

using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)client))
{
   client.SomeMethod();
}
```

My question is: Instead of replacing every instance of my original method call approach; Is there a way to modify my `SvcHelper` and do the creation of the channel in the `SvcHelper` constructor and then simply pass the interface like the following:

```
SvcHelper.Using<ISomethingWebService>(client =>
{
   client.SomeMethod();
}
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want to create a new `ChannelFactory<T>` every call to the Using helper method. They are the most costly thing to construct in the WCF universe. So, at bare minimum, you will want to use a caching approach there.

Second, you don't want to tie yourself to "client" types at all anymore. Just work straight with the service contract interfaces.

Starting from what you've got, here's where I'd go based on how I've done this in the past:

```
public class SvcHelper
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<ChannelFactoryCacheKey, ChannelFactory> ChannelFactories = new ConcurrentDictionary<ChannelFactoryCacheKey, ChannelFactory>();

    public static void Using<TServiceContract>(Action<TServiceContract> action) where TServiceContract : class
    {
        SvcHelper.Using<TServiceContract>(action, "*");
    }

    public static void Using<TServiceContract>(Action<TServiceContract> action, string endpointConfigurationName) where TServiceContract : class
    {
        ChannelFactoryCacheKey cacheKey = new ChannelFactoryCacheKey(typeof(TServiceContract), endpointConfigurationName);

        ChannelFactory<TServiceContract> channelFactory = (ChannelFactory<TServiceContract>)SvcHelper.ChannelFactories.GetOrAdd(
                                                                                                                                cacheKey,
                                                                                                                                missingCacheKey => new ChannelFactory<TServiceContract>(missingCacheKey.EndpointConfigurationName));

        TServiceContract typedChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        IClientChannel clientChannel = (IClientChannel)typedChannel;

        try
        {
            using(new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)typedChannel))
            {
                action(typedChannel);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                clientChannel.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                clientChannel.Abort();
            }
        }

    }

    private sealed class ChannelFactoryCacheKey : IEquatable<ChannelFactoryCacheKey>
    {
        public ChannelFactoryCacheKey(Type channelType, string endpointConfigurationName)
        {
            this.channelType = channelType;
            this.endpointConfigurationName = endpointConfigurationName;
        }

        private Type channelType;

        public Type ChannelType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.channelType;
            }
        }

        private string endpointConfigurationName;

        public string EndpointConfigurationName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.endpointConfigurationName;
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(ChannelFactoryCacheKey compareTo)
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo)
                       ||
                   (compareTo != null
                       &&
                   this.channelType == compareTo.channelType
                       &&
                   this.endpointConfigurationName == compareTo.endpointConfigurationName);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object compareTo)
        {
            return this.Equals(compareTo as ChannelFactoryCacheKey);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.channelType.GetHashCode() ^ this.endpointConfigurationName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm not sure why you had to remove that... unless you've made the methods non-static? I was compiling that sample code just fine before I pasted it. I prefer prefixed method calls for clarity so I always prefix with this. or ClassName. in case of static calls.

Comment: Would I still need to implement caching as well as this method?

Comment: Well I have caching of the ChannelFactory instances in there by channel Type, but I forgot that we actually need to cache by Type+endpointConfiguration name to be a complete implementation. I'll update the implementation to be complete.

Comment: Also shouldn't `public int GetHashCode()` be `public override int GetHashCode()`?

Comment: I'm just using StackOverflow to compile, so ya gotta forgive me for the little stuff. ;P That said the cacheKey thing you actually don't want to change, you just want to use a different variable name. If you change it to what you did you're actually going to be instantiating a ChannelFactory every time. I'll update the sample.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public class SvcHelper
{
    public static void Using<TClient>(Action<TClient> action) where TClient : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable
    {
        ChannelFactory<TClient> cnFactory = new ChannelFactory<TClient>("SomethingWebService");
        TClient client = cnFactory.CreateChannel();
        using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)client))
        {
            action(client);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the type argument passed to the generic `ChannelFactory` class must be an interface type. It says that there's no conversion from interface to `ICommunicationObject`.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to remove "where TClient:ICommunicationObject, IDisposable"